# Rails Active Admin checkboxes not displaying selected options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

```
class ArticleRejectionReason < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :reason 
has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :article_rejection_reasons
end


ActiveAdmin.register Article do
  permit_params article_rejection_reason_ids: []

  f.inputs "Article Details" do
   f.input :article_rejection_reasons, as: :check_boxes, collection: ArticleRejectionReason.all.collect { |r| [r.reason, r.id] }
 end
end
```

Checkboxes(options) are generated as expected. I can save the data into the database.

However, when I hit 'edit' button, I do not see the selected options displayed.

I know how to do this in jQuery. How do I show selected options in active admin?

Update 1:

```
mysql> select * from article_rejection_reasons_articles;
+------------+-----------------------------+
| article_id | article_rejection_reason_id |
+------------+-----------------------------+
|        386 |                           2 |
|        386 |                           4 |
|        386 |                           6 |
+------------+-----------------------------+
```

Update 2:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to rails naming convention, 'has_and_belongs_to_many' should have plural assosciations.

```html
class ArticleRejectionReason < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :reason 
has_and_belongs_to_many :articles /* plural */
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :article_rejection_reasons /* plural */
end


ActiveAdmin.register Article do
  permit_params article_rejection_reason_ids: []
  form do |f|
  f.inputs "Article Details" do
   f.input :article_rejection_reasons, as: :check_boxes, collection: ArticleRejectionReason.all.collect { |r| [r.reason, r.id] }
  end
 end
end
```

[This link may be helpful to you.](http://rails.hasbrains.org/questions/369)

Comment: Hi Sravan, thanks for the reply. I have changed it to plural and it still doesn't show the selected options. Is there anything else so obvious I'm missing out?

Comment: I updated the code in 'ActiveAdmin.register Article' please try that.

Comment: Hi Sravan, thanks for the changes. I already had `permit_params article_rejection_reason_ids: []` in `admin/article.rb`. The data is being saved in the database as well as updated in the question. It's strange why the selected options are not being displayed.

Comment: as you already have assosciation in model change the checkboxes line to, simply `f.input :article_rejection_reasons, as: :check_boxes`